# Is it safe to ignore return values when calling symbols from a C library

Tags: c, llvm, abi

I've been fiddling around with LLVM and wrote a simple compiler. It uses the libc as its standard library. Naturally I have to declare the functions in my IR somehow.

I noticed that the following seems to work:

```
declare void @puts(i8*)
```

In C the function is defined like this:

```
int puts(const char *s);
```

so it should really be

```
declare i32 @puts(i8*)
```

This is a really simple case but I am sure that somewhere along the road I will make mistakes declaring these functions. For instance I was not aware that `puts` returned an int before I read the manpage.

How grave are these mistakes? Does it mess with the stack or does LLVM handle it somehow? What are the security implications of such mistakes?

Note: I was not able to produce any errors with the `void` declaration of `puts`.

Comment: No, it's not safe to ignore return values.  If `puts` fails to write data (eg, the command was redirected to a pipe, and that pipe has been closed), then the program should respond.  Sometimes, the program simply terminates after getting a SIGPIPE, but if you ignore SIGPIPE and don't respond to a failed `puts`, it is quite likely that your program will never terminate.  In general, it is *not* safe to ignore return values.

Comment: I am aware that the return values have semantics and should be dealt with. I am more interested in the implications for the ABI though.

Comment: @Richard: What ABI? For what system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this depends on the calling convention used by your C compiler's ABI. In the conventions used by most C compilers on x86 and x86-64, the return value is passed in a register. Mis-declaring an `int`-returning function as `void` will cause the value of the return register to be ignored (which it would be anyway if you're not using it). This doesn't cause any harm because the caller is responsible for saving the `eax` register anyway.

For example, the following code:

```
void callee(int, int, int);

void caller(void)
{
  callee(1, 2, 3);
}
```

...will be compiled into exact same assembly if you declare `callee` to return `int` instead of `void`.

This applies to "small" return types, i.e. those that consist of an integer, a double-precision floating-point, or a 64-bit integer (which x86 returns in two integer registers). Large return types are handled differently - if you change the declaration of `callee` to something like:

```
struct { char x[100]; } callee(int, int, int);
```

...the calling code will change drastically, despite the passed-in types not having changed. The return structure will now be allocated on the caller's stack, and its address will be passed as a hidden first argument to the callee (this is on x86, things are slightly different on x86-64), which is expected to write the return value to that area.

In other words, as long as you understand the calling convention, and you are careful not to mis-declare functions that return large types by value (which AFAIK don't exist in the standard C and POSIX libraries), the erroneous declaration will work.

Answer (score 3):

Small return values are usually placed in a return value register so ignoring those won't fatally crash. For larger values some ABIs require the caller to allocate stack space and pass it as an invisible first parameter to the function, in this case your program would probably quickly crash since you wouldn't be allocating or passing it.  If you're using an abi that doesn't store previous-frame-pointers I.e. It must know how big it's own stack frame is and the abi allows callees to adjust the stack pointer, this would be fatal as well.

Basically it might work until it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Richard

The answers so far are good but I would consider one big implication is if you are ignoring C function returns that, as part of their functionality, allocate memory or open/create files, etc. etc. and then return some kind of pointer.

Ignoring these will, of course, orphan the memory that will only free up when the program exits (if it makes it that far), leave files open, etc. etc.

Basically, if the function you are calling returns anything **BUT** register values or stack instance values the implications may be significant.

Comment: What you say is correct, but it is also abundantly clear from the comments to the question that Richard is aware of all this. The point of his question was learning something about the implementation of function calls in C, not exonerating the bad practice of ignoring return values.